# “ into the driveway” or “ onto the driveway“?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I’m not sure which one is correct ? Drive into the driveway or drive onto the drive way ?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What have you found in your own research?

Comment: It depends on the context.

Comment: Drive down the parkway until you get to the red house, then park in the driveway.

Comment: @HotLicks and don't forget to pay the toll on the freeway when the highway goes under the river.